# Function to format an HTML string of ul/li/sup/sub into a simplified/resolved strings array which can be later used to display data by looping on it

Tags: javascript, html, string, parsing

I have a similar query like the question: [Function to format an HTML string of ul/li into a nested object with a specific format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72834727/function-to-format-an-html-string-of-ul-li-into-a-nested-object-with-a-specific/72834895?noredirect=1#comment133268899_72834895).

But in my `ul/li/sup` as you can see in the string given below. I don't have a `p` tag instead I have `sup/sub` which also needs to be resolved.

```
var htmlString = "<ul><li>Uses multiple cameras to display a digital overhead image of the area around your vehicle along with Rear Vision Camera or front views<sup>1</sup></li><li>Front and rear dynamic guidelines laid over the display image assist in parking maneuvers by showing the vehicle's path</li><li>It works at low speeds and may help you park and avoid nearby objects.</li><li>You can select additional views on your camera display</li></ul>";
```

I want to convert it into an array from all the information in the `li` tags.

```
[
    "Uses multiple cameras to display a digital overhead image of the area around your vehicle along with Rear Vision Camera or front views1", **views should have 1 as superscript**
    "Front and rear dynamic guidelines laid over the display image assist in parking maneuvers by showing the vehicle's path",
    "It works at low speeds and may help you park and avoid nearby objects.",
    "You can select additional views on your camera display"
]
```

Comment: _"views should have 1 as superscript"_: Do you mean you want to retain the `<sup></sup>` tags in the output array, or do you want [unicode characters (for example)](https://symbl.cc/en/00B9/) instead?

Comment: Why can't you just modify the answer to the linked question for your particular string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The linked question is dealing with nested lists and produces a nested object. Here you have a flat list element, where you only need the top level text values in an array. So it is simpler:

```js
const texts = ul => Array.from(ul.children, li => li.textContent);

const html_string = "<ul><li>Uses multiple cameras to display a digital overhead image of the area around your vehicle along with Rear Vision Camera or front views<sup>1</sup></li><li>Front and rear dynamic guidelines laid over the display image assist in parking maneuvers by showing the vehicle's path</li><li>It works at low speeds and may help you park and avoid nearby objects.</li><li>You can select additional views on your camera display</li></ul>";

const {body} = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html_string, "text/html");
const result = texts(body.children[0]); // Assumed to be the UL
console.log(result);
```

If you need to keep the `<sup>` and other inner tags in tact, then just return the HTML instead of the plain text:

```js
const htmls = ul => Array.from(ul.children, li => li.innerHTML);

const html_string = "<ul><li>Uses multiple cameras to display a digital overhead image of the area around your vehicle along with Rear Vision Camera or front views<sup>1</sup></li><li>Front and rear dynamic guidelines laid over the display image assist in parking maneuvers by showing the vehicle's path</li><li>It works at low speeds and may help you park and avoid nearby objects.</li><li>You can select additional views on your camera display</li></ul>";

const {body} = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html_string, "text/html");
const result = htmls(body.children[0]); // Assumed to be the UL
console.log(result);
```

Comment: What if we have to keep the `<sup>1</sup>` intact

Comment: Then you can always manually map the result of ```body.querySelectorAll(`li`)``` to what you need.

Comment: To keep `<sup>` tags and others, just use the `innerHTML` property. (added to answer)